# Making D3 Bubble Charts Without Children Elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bubble-chart

guys. I've been trying to do some work with some data for a capstone class I am currently in. This data is in Excel and I have converted it to JSON using a converter online. The problem with this data is that it doesn't have children elements and making the children by hand would take hours because it's ~15,000 lines. Is it possible to make bubble charts without using children data? I've tried finding examples and answers, but I have yet to find any.

[Here is an example](https://www.google.com/search?q=D3%20bubble%20chart&safe=off&rlz=1C1ASRM_enUS627US627&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=947&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=HscNVY2pC6m_sQTBjYD4DQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg#imgdii=_&imgrc=L0KCy_g-0JKEJM%253A%3BYdgXynThapdpZM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fouseful.files.wordpress.com%252F2012%252F08%252Ftransactional-services-explorer.png%253Fw%253D700%2526h%253D537%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fblog.ouseful.info%252Fcategory%252Fvisualisation%252Ffeed%252F%253Fwithoutcomments%253D1%3B700%3B537) of what I'm roughly trying to make it look it.

Thanks in advance for any replies!

Comment: why not just convert it properly, instead? export to some "convenient to read in" format for your favourite scripting language, and use that to regenerate the data in a form D3 can work with.

Comment: What does the data currently look like?  Update your question with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform tabular data to nested data using [supergroup](http://sigfried.github.io/supergroup/) or [Underscore.Nest](https://github.com/iros/underscore.nest)